# Genus zero links

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

We know that every link in $S^3$ bounds a Seifert surface, and the genus of a link is defined as the minimal genus among the Seifert surfaces it bounds. It is easy to see that the only genus zero knot is the unknot. Do we have a similar characterization for genus zero links?

Comment: I do not think there is a simple characterization. The one you proposed clearly fails (take the 2-component link given by framing of a nontrivial knot).

Comment: Genus-0 two-component links correspond to 2-cablings of knots. Genus-0 links with more than two components seem less characterizable... Maybe iterated band sums of 2-cablings of knots?